# Adding Up All Values In A File

Tags: python, logging

I have a massive 313,000 Line log that looks like below. I'm trying to find a quick way to add up all the Player Online: `(number)/100`. So just basically add all the (Number) together. Any ideas?

Not looking for Java code, I only know python and batch

Thanks

Example Of Data:

```
[04-28-2018 22:49:30] TPS: 20.0
Memory free: 2394.0/4551.0 (52%)
Players online: 19/100
Total chunks loaded: 8413
Total entities: 1532
```

Comment: Looks like you could use a regular expression for that. Just make sure that you process lines as you read them - don't read the whole file into memory, there's no need for that.

Comment: Do you know a regex command?

Comment: My suggestion is to do some research on Google, find a primer on regular expressions in Java, and try to make some code that does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way is via regular expressions and streams:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Players online: (\\d+)/100");
int total = Files.lines("filename")
    .map(pattern::matcher).filter(Matcher::matches)
    .map(m -> matcher.group(1))
    .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
```

If you're not familiar with streams this turns the file into a stream of strings which are then converted to integers via regular expressions which are then summed up.